# How can I create array of numbers in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c

i trying to create my firsy iphone program and i realize that making an array or matrix of 2 dims is difficult for me... :-(

*how and where i declarer somthing like this (take from java) so all the function can see it:

```
int[] myArray = new int[6];
```

*how can i trnslete this function:

```
  public  int[] sortArray (int[] myArray){
  int tmp;
  for (int x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
   for (int y = x+1; y < 6; y++) {
    if (myArray[y] < myArray[x]) {
     tmp = myArray[x];
     myArray[x] = myArray[y];
     myArray[y] = tmp;
    }
   }
  }
  return myArray;
 }
```

*and how i call this function?

```
sortArray(myArray);
```

thanks for everyone!!!
sharon

Comment: Xcode is an IDE - Objective-C is the language (and Cocoa, UIKit, etc. are frameworks.) :-)

Comment: Your actual question is very unclear and shows no research effort. First you ask how to declare a multidimensional array, then you ask about scope (I think), then you ask about porting a function from one language to another. Can you be more specific? (Also, how does this have four answers? I've got to start putting emoticons and using female names in my questions o_O.)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with one line of code:

```
NSArray *array = @[@[@1, @2, @3],
                   @[@4, @5, @6],
                   @[@7, @8, @9]];
```

Learn about Objective-C literals [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Answer (score 3):

As in C,

```
int twoDArray[3][3];
```

In objective-C

```
NSArray *a=@[@"apple",@"axe",@"ant"];
NSArray *b=@[@"ball",@"book",@"baby"];
NSArray *c=@[@"cup",@"cat",@"cow"];

NSArray *twoDArray=@[a,b,c];
```

or in one statement:

```
NSArray *twoDArray=@[@[@"apple",@"axe",@"ant"],
                     @[@"ball",@"book",@"baby"],
                     @[@"cup",@"cat",@"cow"]];
```

---

EDIT:

NO need to convert that java function to obj-c method.

**To sort the array** :

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id str1, id str2) {
    return [((NSString *)str1) compare:((NSString *)str2) options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

EDIT 2: (Removed unwanted typecast of nsstring to id and back to string)

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return [str1 compare:str2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: if you would declare the objects passed into the block as NSStrings, you wouldnt need the ugly casts.`^(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {…}`

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I changed. And thanks for your help, actually I am in learning phase of blocks..

Answer (score 1):

Declare in your respective .h file

```
NSMutableArray *numbers;
```

Then in your .m file

```
numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     [numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
```

and declare it in your .h as

```
-(NSMutableArray *)sortArray:(NSMutableArray *)numbers;
```

This is the translated method above in Objective-C:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)sortArray:(NSMutableArray *)numbers
{
  NSInteger tmp = 0;
  for(int x = 0; x < [numbers count]; x++)
   for(int y = x + 1; y < 6; y++)
     if([numbers objectAtIndex:y] < [numbers objectAtIndex:x])
     {
       tmp = [numbers objectAtIndex:x];
       [numbers replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:[numbers objectAtIndex:y]];
       [numbers replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:tmp];
     }
  return numbers;
}
```

Also you can call a method in objective-c as follows:

```
[self sortArray:numbers];
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have (at least) two related-but separate questions here.

**1/ how to create an array of numbers**

Objective-C arrays come as immutable NSArrays (fixed contents) or mutable NSMutableArrays (you  can add delete and shuffle contents around). You sort function as written is asking for a mutable array.

To create and populate an immutable array with *NSNumber objects*:

```
NSArray* array = @[@3,@5,@8,@2,@9,@1];   //"@1" is an NSNumber object literal
  //access: array[3] etc
```

Multidimensional:

```
NSArray* arrayOfArrays @[@[@3,@5,@8],@[@2,@9,@1]];
  //access: arrayOfArrays[1][2] etc
```

To create an empty variable-length mutable array

```
NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Create and populate a variable-length mutable array

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@3,@5,@8,@2,@9,@1, nil];  //note nil termination
```

To turn your immutable NSArray into a mutable NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
```

(but take care, this will only render the top level as mutable, if it contains immutable subarrays they will remain immutable)

Objective-C collections (NSArray, NSDictionary, NSSet) can only hold objective-C objects. Therefore if you want to store `int`s or `float`s you need to box them into objective-C NSNumber objects before adding to a collection, and unbox them again to access the value.

```
int x;
float y;

NSNumber xNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:x];  //box
NSNumber yNum = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:y];  //box


x = [xNum intValue]; //unbox
y = [yNum floatValue]; //unbox
```

**2/ how to translate code**

Here is a like-for-like translation:

To create the (mutable) myArray object:

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Populate it:
[myArray addObjects:@3,@6,@8,@1,@9,nil];   //last value is nil to indicate termination
```

The method:

```
- sortArray:(NSMutableArray*)myArray
{
    id tmp;
    for (int x = 0; x < [myArray count]; x++) {
        for (int y = x+1; y < 6; y++) {
            if ([myArray[y] floatValue] < [myArray[x] floatValue]) {
                tmp = myArray[x];
                myArray[x] = myArray[y];
                myArray[y] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To call:

```
[self sortArray:myArray];
```

To declare with object scope, make a property in your @interface section

```
@interface myObject:NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* myArray;
@end
```

You will still need to create myArray before you can use it:

```
self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

but you will be able to set and access it's values from anywhere inside the object thus:

```
self.myArray
```

And - if it is in the public header file @interface section - from outside the object thus:

```
myObject.myArray
```